# detect digits with hopfield Neural network in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to detect digist with hopfield.for any digit let 96 cell ( 8*12).
my data are

```
zero=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
one=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
two=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
three=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
four=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
five=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
six=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
seven=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
eight=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];
nine=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ];

target =[zero;one;two;three;four;five;six;seven;eight;nine];
```

and create a hopfield with newhop

```
 net = newhop(target);
 [Y,Pf,Af] = sim(net,10,[],target);
```

I conclusion this from [matlab website](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/hopfield-unstable-equilibria.html)
but really  I don't know How I achive this
**my project is  detect digits by hopfield network**
appreciate any orgency help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
target =[zero;one;two;three;four;five;six;seven;eight;nine]';
```

Then, for a test:

```
test={three'};
[Y,Pf,Af] = sim(net,{1 5},{},test);
Y{1}
```

You'll notice that Y{1}-three' is very close to zero, which means that your network does its job. Now, in order to recognize the digit you enter, you need to subtract Y{1} from the matrix of digits and check the row the elements of which are closest to zero. This will indicate you the digit you entered.